# Content slider not adjusting first panel height on load

Tags: jquery, slider, coda-slider

I have tried a couple of content sliders that adjust their height to each panel's needs, however when the page first loads, there is extra space underneath the initial panel.  Once they slide to the next panel, the resizing occurs as expected and when it returns to the initial panel it is sized properly.  But when it first loads, there is extra blank space below.

I have tried Coda-Slider2.0 and Unslider.  Both have the same blank space when the page loads.  I have looked through the code for each trying to find the function for re-sizing, but without luck.  I am sure there is something that I could call to get the first panel to resize onload, but so far I am at a loss.

Does anyone have any suggestions on forcing either slider to resize on load?

Comment: do you have an image that is either within the panels or resizing once it has loaded?

Comment: Each panel has an image.  Some are mostly text with a small image, others are purely image.

Comment: you may need to use `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready` then

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to do the same thing using `$(window).load`